# Migration of Oracle Directories from Windows to Linux Server in 12c using GITLAB automation

Tags: azure, powershell, shell, automation, gitlab

I came across a project requirement to migrate DBA directories from oracle running on Windows server to Linux server as a part of Oracle migration project. Considering manual approach it looks easy as we can capture the DDL of Oracle directories, create them on linux with equivalent path(converted to Linux) and then migrate data using WinSCP. Both my DB environments are on Azure IAAS, and target database environment is having CDB-PDB architecture.
However, I need to do the same through Gitlab automated pipeline, and the challenge I am facing is to copy the data from one of the windows directory and copy to its equivalent directory on Linux server.
Lets consider this example for a better insinght:

In Windows I have the following directory structure:

```
E:\Folder1
E:\Folder1\Folder1.1
E:\Folder2
E:\Folder1\Folder1.1\Folder1.1.1
E:\Folder2\Folder2.1
F:\Folder3
```

Lets say each of the above folders have some flat file data(CSVs, TXTs), DB Export Dumps,additional customer data etc.
I need to convert them to Linux equivalent first:

```
/mount/DBDIR/Folder1
/mount/DBDIR/Folder1/Folder1.1
/mount/DBDIR/Folder2
/mount/DBDIR/Folder1/Folder1.1/Folder1.1.1
/mount/DBDIR/Folder2/Folder2.1
/mount/DBDIR/Folder3
```

Then migrate the data from each of these directories to its equivalent Linux directories using automation.

Can anyone help with the possible approach that I can follow here via script.

Thanks...

I am expecting to help with an automated script or logic to migrate oracle directory data from Windows server to Linux.

Comment: Try cloning database : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24628_01/em.121/e27046/cloning_database.htm#EMLCM93230

Comment: We're upgrading the DB to 19c and then migrating directories. Can we clone only the directories.

Comment: See section 14.3.1  - 8